# Get all List values from a map

Tags: apex, map

I have a map of List for custom wrapper object records as below

```
Map<String, List<Custom wrapper object>>
```

I want to get all the records in one list together irrespective of the key of map.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a pretty simple structure to flatten.

```
List<MyWrapper> flattened = new List<MyWrapper>();
for (List<MyWrapper> collection : myMap.values())
    flattened.addAll(collection);
```